# Telling windows 10 which Wifi Ethernet adapter to use on a laptop with an external high gain TP Link Wifi Adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, wireless-router

On my Dell Windows 10 labtop I have an internal Intel wifi adapter. However since that is sometimes not good enough at getting a wifi signal from a far away router I have an additional TP link archer high gain wifi adapter that connects via a USB port .

My problem is sometimes Windows connects via the internal card in spite of me being plugged into the high gain wifi adapter. Is there a way to control which wifi adapter Windows uses. Ideally can I set a priority order so that Windows prefers the TP Link adapter whenever that is plugged in but if not then defaults to the Internal Wifi Intel Adapter?

Screenshot below which shows the correct pairing when Windows is indeed using the TP Link. But at other times when the TP Link appears with a red cross on it I cannot figure out how to force it to switch from the Intel card to the TP Link

PS. I dont want to entirely get rid of the Internal Wifi Card since when I travel etc. I may not always have access to the external Wifi Adapter

[image]

Comment: Simplest thing to do would be to right click the intel adapter and chose Disable. You can usually also turn off the internal wifi in the BIOS or just remove the hardware from inside the laptop (its a simple M.2 slot card that can be removed with ease).

Answer (score 1):

You may set up batch files that will act on the wifi adapters.
This is a simple solution that will just require double-click
on desktop icons.

See the article
[How to enable or disable Wi-Fi and Ethernet network adapters on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-or-disable-wi-fi-and-ethernet-network-adapters-windows-10),
section "How to enable or disable network adapters using Command Prompt",
describing the tools to use, netsh and PowerShell.

For an automatic solution, some work is required to set up an
Event Viewer trigger that will automatically disable one adapter
and enable the other.

The WLAN events are found in the log
*Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows >
WLAN-AutoConfig > Operational*.

A list of the events can be found in the article
[Investigating Wireless Hotspotting Activity In Windows](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/investigating-wireless-hotspoting-activity-windows-marasinghe).
You need to investigate your Event Log to see if the disconnection
happens then in this case a usable event is logged.

You may use in the Event Viewer in the right-side Action pane the
action of "Attach Task To This Event…" to set a trigger,
but a simpler method might be to use the Task Scheduler as described
in the article
[How to Use Event Triggers For Windows Server Monitoring](https://www.virtualmetric.com/blog/how-to-use-event-triggers-for-windows-server-monitoring).

Comment: Thanks! It's amazing that Windows makes such an easy use case so difficult to implement. A simple GUI priority list of WIfi cards would have been the solution.